# how to redirect data from a list view using onitemlisterner to another activity

Tags: android

**please am new to android programming.**
can someone help me with the code to redirect data from a list view in an sqlite database to another activity upon clicking on an item listed
"what i actually mean is that when the program runs and a user clicks on first name as listed a new activity should be open give the proper decription(firstname, lastname, age) for each individual
here is what i have written so far,

```
 `package com.example.mhs;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

  public class P4act extends ListActivity {

  private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "college";
  private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "students";

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Ebola','Moorthy','Cameroon',22);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Eseke','rocks','India',26);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('Achaki','stones','Nigeria',20);");

        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME
                , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                    int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                    results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));



    } 


    catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (sampleDB != null)
            sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
            sampleDB.close();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: so above code redirects u properly?

Comment: no. am hoping someone can help me out

Comment: m unclear with ur goal hence unable to help..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String mySelectedItemValue = results.get(position);
    Intent a = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
    a.putExtra("myValueKey", mySelectedItemValue);
    startActivity(a);
}
```

also: move the 'results' arraylist up to where the DB name is declared etc... and just clear it when you make a fresh call to the db.

to get the value in your new activity

```
String myValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myValueKey");
```